# How to retrieve only one row for Doctrine2 entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I am working with the entities `Price` and `Product`. Every `Product` has several `Prices`. With the getter `Product->getPrices` i can retrieve all `Prices`. Every `Price` has a field `insertedAt` which stores a `DateTime` object.

### My Problem

I want to retrieve only the latest `Price` for a `Product` but i dont know how to do this.

#### Solution (by Maerlyn)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24715756/2139671

### (UPDATE) My next problem

I am using not only then insertedAt-field but also a condition and a source-field. So i need to retrieve the current price for every condition and source. Do you have a solution for that problem, too?

Comment: I have found the ```@Version``` annotation, but i dont know if i could use that for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OrderBy` annotation to define which order the related entities are returned; use it like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"insertedAt" = "DESC"})
 */
private $prices;
```

Then add a method to retrieve the current price:

```
public function getCurrentPrice()
{
    return $this->prices->first();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick and correct answer.

My next problem:
i am using not only then ```insertedAt```-field but also a ```condition``` and a ```source```-field. So i need to retrieve the current price for every condition and source.

Do you have a solution for that problem, too? Thanks!